# Who try to access root@

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I couldn't find how i can have the list of IP that try to access my root@ (it is a command in Linux but i couldn't find it). And than how can I block an IP from this access.

There is someone that try to access my root@ on the server. I need to resolve this problem.

I tried this but don't work :

```
cat access.log| awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c |sort -n
```

Comment: Consider installing `fail2ban` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just type:

```
last root
```

This will give you details of the IP addresses of machines where users logged in as root.

Comment: It actually shows who logged in, not bad attempts, I think you meant `lastb` might be more helpful

Comment: Yeah maybe, although the user wasn't clear as to whether the login was successful or not.

Comment: Fair point, wouldn't it be nice to give both possibilities though?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your Input_file I am providing this solution, so could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk  '{match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/);array[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]} END{for(i in array){print i,array[i]}}'   Input_file
```

If above is not helping you then kindly show us sample Input_file and expected output file too in code tags, so that we could help you in same.

Comment: Could anyone please let me know the reason for -ve on this post please?